# Logging Failed PaginatedList Search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying now for a bit to try to figure out how to successfully tell if my search has succeeded in its search or if it has failed. I am supposed to Log when the search fails AKA when it does not find anything inside the list. I assume it's something to do with a try/catch solution. Sorry if this is an extremely stupid question but I have been looking around and I can't seem to find a way to figure out a way if the search comes back with no data.
The code below is the code I use to search throughout the PaginatedList.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortorder, int pageNumber = 1, string searchString = "", string searchString2 = "", string searchString3 = "")
        {
            var game = from g in _context.Cheats
                           select g;

            ViewData["PlatformSortParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortorder) ? "platform_sort" : "";//default sort
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            ViewData["CurrentFilter2"] = searchString2;
            ViewData["CurrentFilter3"] = searchString3;


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                game = game.Where(b => b.Game.Contains(searchString));

                try
                {

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }

                _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, (EventId)404, "Search string failed while trying to search for {searchString}", searchString);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString2))
            {
                game = game.Where(b => b.CheatName.Contains(searchString2));
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString3))
            {
                game = game.Where(b => b.Platform.Contains(searchString3));
            }

            return View(await PaginatedList<Cheats>.CreateAsync(game, pageNumber, 10));


            //return View(await PaginatedList<Cheats>.CreateAsync(_context.Cheats, pageNumber, 10));
        }
```

This is the code of the PaginatedList class.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
            this.AddRange(items);
        }
        public bool PreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool NextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code as posted doesn't really make a lot of sense - that try/catch block is empty, and your log action happens before you even do anything. Are you trying to determine if the result of `PaginatedList` is an empty collection, or something else?

Comment: Yes I am trying to see if the PaginatedList is an empty collection. If it is empty then the log will then run and say it is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I used in order to log it. Unsure how to use try/catch with this still but this works for my solution.

```
if (game.Count() == 0)
                {
                    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, (EventId)404, "Search string failed while trying to search for {searchString}", searchString);
                }
```